# How to determine INS key state

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-events

I am maintaining an application that displays the key state of <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>, and <kbd>Insert</kbd> keys. I had been using the `user32.dll` method `GetKeyState()` to accomplish this like so:

```
Public Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" Alias "GetKeyState" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer

Public Sub CheckKeys()
    lblCaps.ForeColor = CType(IIf(GetKeyState(Keys.CapsLock) <> 0, Color.Black, Color.Gray), System.Drawing.Color)
    lblIns.ForeColor = CType(IIf(GetKeyState(Keys.Insert) <> 0, Color.Black, Color.Gray), System.Drawing.Color)
    lblNum.ForeColor = CType(IIf(GetKeyState(Keys.NumLock) <> 0, Color.Black, Color.Gray), System.Drawing.Color)
End Sub
```

That worked fine, but now after upgrading the target framework to .NET 4.0, I am getting an error from the Managed Debugging Assistant:

> A call to PInvoke function '[application]::GetKeyState' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

I know I can get the status of the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> keys using `My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock` and `My.Computer.Keyboard.NumLock` boolean values, respectively, but is there a similar way to get the state of the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key?

Comment: Declaration is wrong, argument must be Integer, return value is Short.  Code is wrong too, you must test bit #0 to distinguish current state from pressed state.  Use GetKeyState(Keys.CapsLock) And 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your P/Invoke signature is wrong:

```
Public Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" Alias "GetKeyState" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Short
```

[MSDN states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) `GetKeyState`'s `nVirtKey` parameter is of type `int` and the return type is `short`, that is, a 32-bit signed and 16-bit integer value respectively. In VB.NET, the `Long` type is `Int64`, so you're overwriting the stack.

In VB6, `Long` was 32-bit signed and `Integer` was a 16-bit signed value and `Short` wasn't a keyword, so VB.NET's changes were breaking.

Change your parameter to `ByVal nVirtKey As Integer` and the return type to `As Short`.

I note that the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key, unlike Caps-Lock and Num-Lock, does not have a systemwide state, and it varies per-application or even per-control. I believe (though am uncertain) that maintaining the state of the Insert key is your responsibility and that `GetKeyState` will not work as you intend with the Insert key in particular.

Comment: And return value is a SHORT

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I had been using that signature for at least a few years and never had any issues until upgrading the target framework to .NET 4.0. Maybe the old framework wasn't as picky, or maybe wasn't using the Managed Debugging Assistant. Thanks!